# Team Services deploy to on-premise Service Fabric without exposed endpoint

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a Service Fabric cluster on-premise and would like to deploy code to it from Visual Studio Team Services.  We use this cluster for testing and it does not have an endpoint exposed to the outside world.  It is only accessible internally from inside our network.

From inside Team Services the normal way to deploy a Service Fabric application is with the "Service Fabric Application Deployment" task.  This task requires a "Cluster Connection" parameter, or link to the Service Fabric Service endpoint that Team Services can access.  On this cluster I can't provide an endpoint to the outside world, so this method won't work.

Is there a good, accepted way of accomplishing this?  I'm considering looking at having an Agent on one of the Service Fabric nodes that can run a PowerShell script as part of the build process.  I can kick off a PowerShell script on the node as part of the build process.  If I could retrieve the artifacts from Team Services with this script I believe the rest of the release would be relatively straightforward.

Is this a good line of thought, or is there a more straightforward way to deploy to Service Fabric from Team Services without exposing an endpoint?

Comment: Running an Agent inside the network means you should be able to access the endpoint in the regular way, right?

Comment: My understanding is that the Agent pulls "deployment request" and the artifacts from Team Services.  Team Services isn't able to see inside the network, but the target machine polls Team Services to see if there is a new deployment to be made.

Comment: The Agent installed on the local machine should have access to the endpoint.  Are you suggesting that the "Service Fabric Application Deployment" task may be able to see an endpoint exposed by the Build Agent?

Comment: The agent connects out to vsts, but can execute tasks locally.

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding.  If I can get the artifacts to the agent it should be trivial to run the PowerShell task to install the release.  I wasn't sure on how to get the build artifact off of Team Services after building.  After reviewing it looks like this is a good path to pursue.

Comment: pls let us know if /when it works

Comment: Just need to make sure the  on-premise Service Fabric can be access from agent machine (specified in release definition), do not need to be accessible from VSTS. Also the artifact can be download to the agent machine. (the agent is used to connect to VSTS, the agent machine do not need to be accessible from internet). duongthaiha is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the same set up and using VSTS. We set up a On-Prem agent pool where agent is within our network. The agent is hook with VSTS so build and release can be trigger from VSTS. Agent have access to the artifact on VSTS and can download it for deployment. The different might be we set up a service fabric end point instead of using powershell.

Its a very simple set up and works well for us.Good luck

Comment: We were able to get this working.  I was a little confused on the release definition tasks on the difference between an "agent phase", which runs from Team Services, and a "deployment group phase", which utilizes an agent running on a target/local machine.  Thanks to everyone for your help!